# React Native Expo: Trouble Saving an Expo ImagePicker image to a local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to save an image that the user either uploads from their phone or takes with the camera. So far, I can get the image from both camera or photo gallery and get the URI of the file. However, when I try to save the file to a local folder (Images) in the app I run into issues.

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const FormSubmit = ({navigation, route}) => {
      const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

      ...

      const pickImage = async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      });

      console.log(result);

      if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
      }
    };

    const takeImage = async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      });

      console.log(result);

      if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
      }
    };

    ...

       <Button
                style = {styles.button}
                title="Submit"
                        onPress={ async () => {
                          await FileSystem.moveAsync({
                            from: image,
                            to: FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'Images/'
                        });
                        }}
                color="#19AC52"
            />
```

Again, I am trying to save the uploaded image to a local folder called "Images". This is the unhandled promise request message I get when trying to submit:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-10.69.14.83-DOH_Mobile_V1/ImagePicker/e556a2a3-692b-47bb-8a8b-0731883c33e9.jpg' could not be moved to 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-10.69.14.83-DOH_Mobile_V1/Images/']
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:103:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter\build\NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules\expo-file-system\build\FileSystem.js:69:17 in moveAsync
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\expo-file-system\build\FileSystem.js:65:7 in moveAsync
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:691:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:628:6 in _receiveSignal
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:524:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:500:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:597:41 in executeDispatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:621:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2521:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
at [native code]:null in forEach
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:836:4 in forEachAccumulated
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2546:20 in runEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2702:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2639:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17712:13 in batchedUpdates$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Maybe I am missing something but this error message is not very helpful in figuring out what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to make it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly install `expo-media-library` from [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/)

Then create a fucntion to save file to device

```
  const SaveToPhone = async (item) => {
    // Remember, here item is a file uri which looks like this. file://..
    const permission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (permission.granted) {
      try {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(item);
        MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Images', asset, false)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('File Saved Successfully!');
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('Error In Saving File!');
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Need Storage permission to save file');
    }
  };
```

Then your Button should look like this

```
<Button
  style={styles.button}
  title="Submit"
  onPress={() => SaveToPhone(image)}
  color="#19AC52"
/>
```

Also on the top import like this

```
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
```

See Working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/saving-file-example)

Comment: First of all thank you for this. But is there any reason that I can't use FileSystem? Is my current approach completely unfeasible or was this just the way that you knew how to do it?

Comment: `FileSystem.documentDirectory` would not show up in your device folder....I always used `expo-media-library` for this purpose(saving file to device)

Comment: What do you mean by "show up"? Let me clarify in case I'm misunderstanding. I don't really care if the image is saved anywhere in the app on the device. If that works then sure that's fine. But if I could get it to save in the proper folder inside the project that would be great too.

Comment: The function that I wrote i.e, `SaveToPhone` will save the file to a proper folder called `Images` as per your requirement

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked haha. I know that your code will work and I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does anyone know how to save the image to the local expo directory?

Comment: Doesn't this save files to some shared location accessible by multiple apps? Which for security reasons is not usually what someone wants?

Comment: What does this line do? `const permission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();` **where** is that requesting permissions to read/write files?

Answer (score 0):

Author forgot add file name in this line "to: FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'Images/'"