# React Native Expo: Trouble Saving an Expo ImagePicker Image to the Apps Directory

Tags: react-native, expo

In this post, [React Native Expo: Trouble Saving an Expo ImagePicker image to a local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386164/react-native-expo-trouble-saving-an-expo-imagepicker-image-to-a-local-folder), a user asked about saving a user-selected image to a local file on the users device. However, I want to save a image to the expo apps main directory. Below is the code I have that uses expo's image picker. The code allows the user to pick an image from their device. I just need help writing the selected image to the app's directory. Thanks for the help!

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
    });
    console.log(result);
    
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
    var inputPath = result.assets[0].uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileSystem.readAsStringAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options) to read the image data and then [FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemwriteasstringasyncfileuri-contents-options) to write the data to [FileSystem.documentDirectory](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemdocumentdirectory) i.e. application directory.